# Spline interpolation library in cpp

Tags: c++, geometry, interpolation, curve, bezier-curve

Have been searching a lot for a good spline interpolation library in cpp, came across one, which is the famous Eigen library , having the unsupported counterpart for spline fitting.<[Here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/structEigen_1_1SplineFitting.html#a7bd937fdcfa168dbdc27932886a4da9f)>.
I need spline fitting API that also accepts derivatives.

Eigen's **InterpolateWithDerivatives** API claim to offer that but it is not without bugs. What alternatives do I have?

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/math/doc/html/interpolation.html

Answer (score 1):

So you have a series of points and, at each point, a supplied derivative?

Is a piecewise cubic sufficient or does it need higher derivative continuity?  If the former is ok, then [Cubic Hermite Splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline) will do the job. (If you need, they can be trivially mapped into cubic Beziers)